# Media query width 100% not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

[Here](https://codepen.io/spencer-ryan/pen/aEQedW) is a link to the codepen for the code that I am working on. I am trying to get it so that if the device width is less than 540px, the width of the wrapper goes from 33.33% to 100%, however it doesn't seem to be doing so.

My media query is as follows:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  #wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

My normal css for the wrapper is as follows:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 33.3%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put that `media query` BELOW the other rules in the stylesheet. The way you have it now (i.e. media query at the beginning of your stylesheet) it's overwritten by the general rule (containing `width: 33.3%;`) which follows below it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyPRVG